Macros in C language cannot be expanding correctly
I wrote the following macro in C language：
#define STR(x) #x

I expect the following call to produce the result "11"：
STR(5+6)

But the actual result it produces is "5+6"
How can I write macros to achieve the results I want? Is it possible to implement it in C or C++ language?

The preprocessor has no clue what numbers are let alone what this strange cross symbol does. What are you trying to accomplish and why did you decide on macros as a solution?

@Yunnosch Why would they explain that when it isn't true. #if 5+6 == 11

you can write a similar constexpr function in C++20, but not before it unfortunatly.

@Yunnosch The preprocessor is not working with text, but pre-processor tokens and the grammatical rules for such. In some preprocessor commands like #if, integer constant expressions are evaluated. I had written an answer explaining all of this but now the question is closed, so the OP will have to do with some over-simplification "macros are text replacement" answer instead...

@Lundin Ok, I bow before that level of detail and precision. (No sarcasm; just a little smile, but a very respectful one.)

@Botje: If the preprocessor has no clue what numbers are, why does #if 5+6 == 11 work?

Macros are text replacements[1] done by the C Preprocessor; a tool that runs over your code before the compiler itself ever sees it, and consequently, before any compile-time constant expressions (such as 5+6) are evaluated. The preprocessor can do some arithmetic and comparisons to implement conditional compilation via the #if / #elif / #else directives, but no evaluation is performed in macro expansions outside of such conditional expressions (Thanks to @interjay for pointing this out).
Most importantly, the preprocessor has no notion of the language you're writing in. It doesn't know any of the syntax or semantics of either C or C++.
This is the main reason why in the C++ world, macros are generally considered "evil" (read: should be avoided unless absolutely necessary).
Note that the result you want here, parsing a compile-time-evaluated number into a compile-time-evaluated string, cannot be generally achieved even in the most recent C++ standard revision. constexpr strings do exist, but they do not survive long: See Is it possible to use std::string in a constant expression?
Bottom line: Can't be done, you have to do it at runtime.

[1]
As @Lundin has correctly pointed out, "text replacement" is an oversimplification here. The preprocessing rules implement a set of functions that operate on well-defined tokens, not just on any arbitrary string. For example, processing STR(x) #x with the expression STR(1+1) produces the string constant "1+1" (not simply the replacement #1+1 as you'd expect from a regular macro expansion).
The core issue remains however that the preprocessing is a single-pass run over your code whose language has different rules from C or C++ because it was designed to save you typing work on your files and automatically prepare them before they're given to the compiler.
Nontheless, @Lundin is right in that calling the preprocessor a pure text replacement tool doesn't do it justice.

The preprocessor does evaluate constant expressions in #if directives. But it doesn't do it when expanding macros outside of conditionals.

@interjay true but you can't both evaluate and stringify

Thanks, I added that detail to the answer.

The preprocessor is part of C and C++, contrary to popular belief it is not some magical separate entity. It is not just doing text replacement, macros follow grammatical rules stated by the language standard and works with pre-processor tokens. The OP does end up with "5+6" right? Not #5+6 which would have been the case if it worked with text replacement.

@Lundin True, there's a popular notion that the preprocessor is entirely separated from the language when in fact the preprocessing rules are in the language standard. But the core issue is that those preprocessing rules are effectively a language of their own, with their own instructions and operators (such as '#'), separate from the semantics of C and C++. There are no function calls, no type system, and no structured programming.
